# VS2013 Pro: debug web site on remote IIS

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2013

I have just tried to open a VS2012 project (VB.net web site) in VS 2013 Professional RTM and the "Start Options" dialog does not allow me to enter a custom server.

Under "Start Options" all I see is a disabled text box for "Base URL"

Any idea how I can enable this option so I can enter the address of the web site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft support, this is currently not possible using VS2013:

> The product group will look into the possibility to add this
>   functionality back. They are looking into adding it back (but it is
>   not guaranteed) in Update 1.

Comment: It's crazy when new versions lose features their predecessors had.  It's very much going backwards.  A [Connect item on this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806314/cannot-debug-website-projects-using-iis-in-visual-studio-2013) and [UserVoice item here](https://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41199-general-asp-net/suggestions/4981678-reintroduce-the-use-of-iis-with-web-site-projects-).

Comment: Update 1 fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
You need to open your .sln and edit the file with your custom server like this :

```
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "Project name", "**your custom server url**", "{029F2DEE-E3D8-488E-9719-AA0C4B9DB9BD}"
```

**And set `UseIISExpress` to `false`.**

Comment: Thank you very much, I have tried this but once I open up the solution in VS2013, my custom server information gets replaced with http://localhost:12131 even though I set UseIISExpress to false.